# Find the closest or the nearest path in sql

Tags: sql, path, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have a table(table1) consists of 5 columns in this order

```
date  |   x   |   y    |    z    |     t
...   | 10.24 | 12.01  |    6    |     7
...   |  42   |   18   |    12   |     1
```

and ....
This table has 5 million records

I have another table(table2) like table1 structure but it has only 10 rows
I want to find the closest path in table1.
I use this method to calculate distance between two points

```
sqrt(pow(table2.x-table1.x,2) + pow(table2.y-table1.y,2) + pow(table2.z-table1.z,2) + pow(table2.t-table1.t,2))
```

what is the fastest way to find the nearest ones in table1.
data of the table2 changes every 10 minutes

Comment: `I want to find the closest path in table1` ... can you explain what this means?  Maybe show more sample input data _and_ the expected output.

Comment: Unless you can heuristically limit how many in table 1 you have to check, you are forced to read the entire table and run it through the formulae. No mention of which database is being used is made - ideally you are on one with geo-spatial support which could alter the problem at least.

Comment: How many records do change in table2? Only one or most of them? I'm thinking about indexed view, but it wouldn't make sense if all of rows change...

Comment: I think you could try to ask this on dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You could look into GIS extensions.  These implement alternative indexing structures (R-trees) that speed up such searches.

Comment: Tnx a lot, actually the table1 has 5 million records each record represents a point which is defined in 4 dimensions. table2 has 10 points in 4 dimensions  I want to find the most similar one to the current line.